# For loop json files in Python

Tags: python

I have 10 json files called `Herald500_2005`, `Herald500_2006`.... `Herald500_2015`. I am trying to carry the same search of keywordswords in each file. Instead of doing it one by one I would like to be able to do it in a loop. So far I have tried the following code:

```
for i in range(5,15):
    df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('Herald500_200i.json')])
# Parse dates and set index
    df.date = pandas.to_datetime(df.date)
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
# match keywords
    matchingbodies = df[df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords3))&df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords2))&df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords1))].body
# Count by month
    counts = matchingbodies.groupby(lambda x: x.month).agg(len)

    print "TH 200i" 
    print counts
```

By running this code I am getting the following error:

```
<ipython-input-9-76f2d2649df0> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(5,15):
----> 2     df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('Herald500_200i.json')])
      3 # Parse dates and set index
      4     df.date = pandas.to_datetime(df.date)
      5     df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Herald500_200i.json'
```

Any idea how to correct the code?

Kind regards

Comment: You have 11 files, not 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use *string formatting* to get the `i` value into the string:

```
open('Herald500_200%d.json' % i)
```

Or:

```
open('Herald500_200{0}.json'.format(i))
```

Or, since these are *years* and to simplify handling the leading zero formatting problem, just loop over the years directly:

```
for year in range(2005, 2016):  # note the 2016 here - the upper bound is non-inclusive
    df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('Herald500_%d.json' % year)])
```

Comment: Works excelent, but the only problem is that when reaching to 2010, it tries to get 20010, I guess I could fix it with for i in range(05,15) and open('Herald500_20%d.json' % i)

Comment: Works great @alecxe!